# Java cant move something from a stack to a queue

Tags: java, stack, queue, shunting-yard

So I'm writing a function to perform the shunting yard algorithm on some numbers/operators. The issue is that I have a loop at the end that adds all the remaining operators to the output queue, but for some reason they are not being added. I have tested it and the program enters the loop, and the stack has numbers in it before it goes into the loop but they never get added to the queue, the stack is also empty after going through the loop, so it seems that the operators are being popped from the stack but not added to the queue. Here is the relevant bit of code:

```
while(operatorStack.empty() != true)
{
    System.out.println("Hello");
    outputQueue.add(operatorStack.pop());
}
```

EDIT:

My implementations of stack and queue are:

```
Queue<Object> outputQueue = new LinkedList<Object>();

Stack<Character> operatorStack = new Stack<Character>();
```

Comment: your code is too short. We need to see more i think.

Comment: What implementation of stack and queue are u using. Also, `while(!operatorStack.empty())` is more clear

Comment: would be helpful to see your stack and queue implementations

Comment: It sounds like your Stack is working; can we see how you implemented a Queue?

Comment: I've edited my post to include the implementations.

Comment: what do you get in the middle step of operatorStack.pop(). did you try to check in debug what is stored there/ type/ etc.

Comment: Sorry, I dont know how to check that, I've tried debugging it but how do you find what is stored in the middle of a line?

Comment: Do a printline of a peek operation on the queue after you add the item from the stack.

Comment: Ah, I just tried that, and the queue is still only contains the operands

Comment: If it would help, I could post the whole class, it's pretty long though.